# preg_match to match url with multiple languages

Tags: preg-match

i was using standard preg_match for making url excluding

```
  http://domainlllll.com/
```

and it was working without any issue

```
  preg_match("/^[0-9a-z_\/.\|\-]+$/",$url)
```

but now i want to support multiple languages so i used this and it is also working without any problem

```
   preg_match("/\S+/",$url)
```

my url is

```
link/kn/some-word-গরম-এবং-সেক্সি-ইমেজ/611766
```

but i want to exclude some special characters which is hackers favorite like single quotes and other. i dont want to exclude all special character as few are part of few languages and it will break those languages in link

Any guide will be great

Comment: Do you want to match with the `^\S+$` pattern, but add some excluded chars to it? Like `'/^[^\s\'"]+$/'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  shows 157ms in matching https://regex101.com/r/xB0dZ6/1 this much time ?????

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xB0dZ6/1 shows 14ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, the `/^[0-9a-z_\/.\|\-]+$/` regex requires the whole string to match the patterns, 1+ chars from the defined ranges (digits, lowercase ASCII letters)  and sets. The `/\S+/` regex does not require a full string match since there are no anchors, `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string), and matches 1 or more non-whitespace chars anywhere inside a string.

If you plan to match strings that only contain non-whitespace symbols and NOT quotes, use

```
preg_match('~^[^\s\'"]+$~', $url)
```

The `^[^\s\'"]+$` matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\s\'"]+` -  1 or more chars other than whitespace (`\s`), `'` and `"`
- `$` - end of string (better use `\z` instead if you need to validate a string).